# The graphs in which radius is equal to diameter

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I was working out on a problem. Came out with a result in $C_n$: radius = diam. Worked out on other few graphs where radius=diam. Can we generalize the result? A little hint will be helpful. The examples on which I worked out, turned out to be regular too. Thanks

Comment: For a non-regular example, add an edge to $C_5$; the radius and diameter are still $2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious family of such graphs are [vertex transitive graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph).  All vertex transitive graphs are self-centered (every vertex has the same eccentricity).  Their complements are also vertex transitive graphs and thus are also self-centered.  These will always be regular graphs, however.